# Lithium discharger with what I have laying around the house. Review pls?

Tags: safety, thermal, discharge

I'm trying to MacGyver my way around discharging some lithium ion cells down to a set voltage I can safely store them for maximum life.

My main issue was I don't have a decent voltage reference as low as these 1865 go such as a linear regulator or Zener so I used a LED.
Basically I compare the drop across the LED with the voltage across a trimmable voltage divider using an opamp with no feedback, feed the signal to a n-mosfet which drains ~350mA over a 7.5ohm / 5W resistor.

**First issue**: Thermal stability
Using a hair drier to test thermal stability shows I can set the device to discharge the cell down to 3.5 V, but apply heat and the cutoff point goes to 3.3V. I think the main culprit is the LED. Does anyone know any way to make this more stable? Like using a similar LED to balance things out? Got to say: I don't expect hairdryer temperatures on my led any time soon. But I'm no expert in thermal runaways

**Second issue**: Safety
Should I be able to sleep while I have this thing working? Does it come down to implementation or is this simple circuit intrinsically unstable toe to thermal run-off potential?

**Third issue**: Do I need to cool that 5W resistor? Is it safe if it goes up to 60*C as long as it's rated to 5W? Gotta say, it's pretty close to maximum rating. I have two of those. I could use both in series, but I'd rather pull more current. I also have a 1ohm 100w resistor, maybe 8.5ohm  (the two combined) is the sweet spot? Or maybe I should limit the base voltage in the mosfet.

**Thank you.**

[Circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWK0AckDMYwE4As3sA2SQgdgCYFsRcIkFIQEBTAWiwCgAlcSXR9OUZg+jcihRQp-EOlSTGi6Ag4AnENlKFZQjVppwpDeBwDuvBNv7CRuA4rXhbOm33tSRJsIXJO31vztcXElfABNmADMAQwBXABsAF1Z45jDwKSVIMDM9K0MRciDDSA5o3hkA20Z8bUkwJHYkT3hhaFxyH1J0FG6hKkpScHae9EJCdFJIbGytetbSgHNAmhCV3EI7B3NNbUFhURcoXKw3fYqBXVKwUjsUInciGrW6VuRaaYWvtwAVAAtVMwAM5-AD28TCJ0OtV4EhoD2uPgu8O0BF8MPCUTiSRSaQyimQ2UcaJRGmCpIOcA4kVhkhhWBQQQegmGSBgkHIjgZQTQTkZR0YpGUJ2c525Ao4ACMnMRZKQIGByDgaJhjuZxQhFXy7AhyaUduSYXgdXrcthxKtJObJLqtmaLbaySa7erIHDHRrTctrUxyfdtI6HOoRHD6W6bXreK0oe7ycbfS6NLKArt3KUAB5+KwdJy0VZIO4gLhRZiAgB2AGNmBxM546N5eOhGJrqIWAJJlsIASwr0USoNUHB6mQySAAauDEtFFtWgA):

Forgot to say: I used [this mosfet](https://ro.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/TN0702N3-G?qs=b1HjDA41YmFb%2FZmSTijIVQ%3D%3D)

And measured

- VBE = 1.5v
- Rds 1.1ohm
- temperature: 43*C

[image: 1865 discharger]

Comment: What OpAmp/Comparator are you using? And how are you powering it? The battery voltage itself is probably not enough.

Comment: the resistor is safe to more than 100C  (not safe to touch, but it won't break).

Comment: Actually the opamp seems to be working but you might be right. The specs show it normally needs at least 3v VDD. I can easily tune this to lower than that and perhaps break a battery or set things on fire.
It's a [TLC27L2CP](https://www.ti.com/store/ti/en/p/product/?p=TLC27L2CP)
Speakingn of breaking things. I can confirm it killed a lithium cell. LED is down, and battery now shows 2.1v. A lot less than the 3.7 I thought I set it to using a bench power supply.

Comment: The reason I broke a battery is that a connection came loose in the voltage divider basically making the led drop always 0 volts. Damn 23523 AWG wires and breadbboards...